# python: how to only output the integers in a list of both integers and floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem. I was wondering if there was a way to only output the integers in a list of both integers and floats.

this is what I have written so far: (sory about how it's formatted)

```
# Greet the user
print("Welcome to the Common Divisors Machine!")

# Initialize variable
confirm = 'yes'

# Start nested checking against variable to start or not
while confirm != ('n' or 'N' or 'no' or 'No'):
    x = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))

    # Validating the variable "x"
    while x <= 0:
        x = int(input("Error, please enter a positive, non-zero number: "))
    # Initializing for the first part of the FOR loop
    i = 1
    y = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))

    # Validating the variable "y"
    while y <= 0:
        y = int(input("Error, please enter a positive, non-zero number: "))
    # Initializing variable for the second part of the FOR loop
    h = 1
    print("The common divisors, excluding 1 and 2, are: ")
    # Starting the FOR loop
    # Setting the variable initialized earlier to be used against "x"
    for i in range (1, x - 1):
        # Nested the second part to run within the first part
        for h in range (1, y - 1):
            # Dividing the user input
            a = x / i
            b = y / h

            # Nesting a WHILE loop to run within both of the FOR loops
            # to print the output of both
            # Also checking whether the answers are the same
            while a == b and a != 1 and a != 2:
                # Printing the output
                print(b)
                # Re initializing "a" so that it will loop back to the top
                a = 0

    # Checking whether or not the user would like to check for more divisors
    confirm = input("Would you like to continue(y/n)? ")
 # Exiting comment
print("Thank you for using the Common Divisors Machine!")
```

Is this even possible?

here is a sample output for those who were asking:

```
Welcome to the Common Diviors Machine!
Please enter the first number: 150
Please enter the second number: 300
The common divisors, excluding 1 and 2, are: 
150.0
75.0
50.0
37.5
30.0
25.0
21.428571428571427
18.75
16.666666666666668
15.0
13.636363636363637
12.5
11.538461538461538
10.714285714285714
10.0
9.375
8.823529411764707
8.333333333333334
7.894736842105263
7.5
7.142857142857143
6.818181818181818
6.521739130434782
6.25
6.0
5.769230769230769
5.555555555555555
5.357142857142857
5.172413793103448
5.0
4.838709677419355
4.6875
4.545454545454546
4.411764705882353
4.285714285714286
4.166666666666667
4.054054054054054
3.9473684210526314
3.8461538461538463
3.75
3.658536585365854
3.5714285714285716
3.488372093023256
3.409090909090909
3.3333333333333335
3.260869565217391
3.1914893617021276
3.125
3.061224489795918
3.0
Would you like to continue(y/n)?
```

I do not want it to display the long decimals, only the whole numbers

Comment: I don't see how your question is relevant to the code you posted, where is the list? Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to ask is, "How do I determine if one number is evenly divisible by another?"

The answer to that question is the [`modulo operator: %`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

The modulo operation basically returns the integer remainder after division of two numbers. So the result of `6 % 5` will be 1, `7 % 5` will be 2, etc.

You can check if `a % b == 0` in order to determine that yes, a is divisible by b.

Comment: Not quite what I was asking, but thanks. I am trying to find common denominators between two numbers. I did word it wrong, though. I only want whole numbers, and it is giving me a lot of decimal numbers. any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `%`. When you are computing `a = x / i`, you should first check if `x % i == 0`. Because if so, you'll get an integer result when you divide `x/i`, otherwise you'll get a fractional number: `15 % 2 == 0`? no. `15/2 = 7.5` (fractional result)